# argstream.h library on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, image-processing, compiler-errors

I have to compile a C++ program that includes argstream.h library.
But when I try to compile, this is the result:

```
fatal error: argstream.h: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me to fix this thing?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I found a argstream.h file on the web. I put that in the /usr/local/include folder. But now when I compile I received a lot of errors related to the argstream library.

Comment: Have you tried searching on the web? Otherwise apt-file is a good way to find stuff like that.

Comment: Unfortunately apt-file gets no results. And on the web I haven't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard library.

Look here.
http://freecode.com/projects/argstream/

Comment: And how can I use that with gcc?? The website in not accessible

Comment: Confirmed. looks like you're outta luck. 
I think the main point here is that you need the library installed or the source code + the .h header file. This way the compiler can find it.